# Mutually dependent select list input controls

Tags: r, shiny

I have two selectInput controls.  Depending on what the user selects in the first selectInput control, I want to change the choices in the second selectInput (to choices that make sense given the value selected in the first control).  And vice-versa.

Can this be done?  If so, how?

Comment: [Please don’t add the tag to the title of the question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076/1968) It’s unnecessary, since that’s explicitly what *tags* are for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would use if statements to evaluate the input from the first selections with boolean logic.

```
if(selection1=="x"): buttonList<- aList
if(selection1=="y"): buttonList<- bList
if(selection1=="z"): buttonList<- cList
```

Where each list has a different set of possibilities to be dropped into the next input control as choices relative to the first. It is not too difficult.